# Asymptotics of Bessel function for real arguments

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I am trying to calculate the following asymptotic behaviour:

```
Normal@Series[BesselK[1, r \[CapitalLambda]] / BesselK[1, \[CapitalLambda]], {r, 0, 1}]
```

but for $\Lambda$ real and positive. I have tried with:

```
Assuming[{\[CapitalLambda] \[Element] Reals, \[CapitalLambda] > 0;},Normal@Series[BesselK[1, r \[CapitalLambda]] /   BesselK[1, \[CapitalLambda]], {r, 0, 1}]]
```

but I still get a complex output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Normal@Series[BesselK[1, r Λ]/BesselK[1, Λ], {r, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Λ > 0]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use

```
Simplify@Normal@Series[BesselK[1, r Λ]/BesselK[1, Λ], {r, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Λ > 0]
```

or

```
Simplify[Normal@ Series[BesselK[1, r Λ]/ BesselK[1, Λ], {r, 0, 1}], 
    Assumptions ->  Λ > 0]
```

or

```
Assuming[{ Λ > 0}, 
  Simplify[Normal@ Series[BesselK[1, r Λ] / BesselK[1, Λ], {r, 0, 1}]]]
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or